# Use of comma before or after "specifically"?

Tags: grammaticality

> I am interested in software engineering specifically software testing and program analysis.

Do I need to use a comma before or after specifically in the above sentence?

Comment: Before, to prevent your reader from parsing your sentence as meaning that your interest is specifically in software engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a punctuation/typesetting issue, so there will be several potential solutions. As the writer, how do you want your readers to interpret the sentence *and* how do you want them to flow with the sentences around it? Where do want the pause? What you don't want are your readers needing to re-read because of ambiguity.

Because you don't have two complete sentences connected by an adverb, your grammar is fine either way. Taking into account Rat's comment, I'd write this

**I am interested in software engineering--[m-dash] specifically, software testing and program analysis.**